# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named after poetry install

Tags: pip, dockerfile, pyinstaller, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

Using DockerFile to build python application, Library will be built from source code added in

`[tool.poetry.dependencies]` facing problem when the container runs it raises `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasa_addons'`

Snap from pyproject.ml

```
rasa-addons = {path = "rasa_addons"}
```

Snap from build code in DockerFile

```
RUN python -m venv /opt/venv && \
  . /opt/venv/bin/activate && \
  pip install --no-cache-dir -U 'pip<20' && \
  poetry install --extras full --no-dev --no-root --no-interaction && \
  poetry build -f wheel -n && \
  pip install --no-deps dist/*.whl && \
  rm -rf dist *.egg-info
```

It appears in pip listed libraries

```
Installing rasa-addons (2.2.5.2 /build/rasa_addons)
```

Comment: What are the commands to run the code? You only show the parts where you install things, but not how your run them...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the code from here : https://github.com/botfront/rasa-for-botfront
Build `docker build -f docker/Dockerfile_botfront -t rasa-local:latest ` run `docker run -p 5005:5005 rasa-local:latest`

Comment: Have you tried being more explicit and setting`/opt/venv/bin/rasa` as entry point? -- Otherwise I don't know what could be the source if the issue, the dockerfile seems okay although maybe unnecessarily complicated, so I might not be exactly following what is happening.